# For increment is not working properly in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to increment my loop.At first I am initialization i=0 and k=0 and then i want to initialization i with that increment value.I have tried these code below but it is not working.Please help me out from these problem

```
for (i = 0; i < totalcount; i++)
{
  for (k = 0; k < totalstudent; k++)
  {
      dt.Rows.Add(companyname[i], companyemail[i], studentname[k]);
  }
}

i = totalcount;
k = totalstudent;
totalcount += totalcount;
totalstudent++;
```

But if i write in another way its getting increment.i have attached my below code.But that is not proper way.i can't write for loop again and again

```
for (i = 0; i < totalcount; i++)
{
  for (k = 0; k < totalstudent; k++)
  {
    dt.Rows.Add(companyname[i], companyemail[i], studentname[k]);
  }
}

for (i = totalcount; i < totalcount+totalcount; i++)
{
  for (k = totalstudent; k < totalstudent+totalstudent; k++)
  {
    dt.Rows.Add(companyname[i], companyemail[i], studentname[k]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not "increment a loop". It's not clear at all what you're trying to do here. (How did this question got upvoted, I wonder.)

Comment: I bet the issue is with these lines : i = totalcount;
k = totalstudent; What is the value of the totalcount and totalstudent ? Please let me know.

Comment: value of totalcount=3 and totalstudent=1